# What does scanf,memset, and a couple while's in C++ mean in Java?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, input

So I have been working on understanding an algorithm and I found a C++ code for it on the internet but the problem is that I know Java but am really unfamiliar with C++ so I'm having some trouble understanding it. This part in particular:

```
int m, i, j, len;
char temp[50];
char stuff[100][100];


while(scanf("%d",&m)!=EOF)
{
    while(m--)
    {
        scanf("%s",temp);

        len = strlen(temp);
        for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
            for(j=0;j<=len;j++)
                memset(stuff[i][j],0,sizeof(char)*4);

    }
}
```

Ok, so here is what I'm thinking about the parts I don't understand. If someone could tell me if i'm on the right track I'd be super grateful.

```
while(scanf("%d",&m)!=EOF)
```

For this part, since there is no input file or anything like that and m hasn't been initialized. I'm thinking it means that it will take in user input of ints or doubles until the EOF char is given in the console. That input will be saved as m. I'm just confused about the while loop. Is something ongoing? m is just one int so I don't really understand that.

```
while(m--)
```

Like equivalent to for(i = m; i>=0; i--) ?

```
scanf("%s",temp);

    len = strlen(temp);
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
        for(j=0;j<=len;j++)
            memset(stuff[i][j],0,sizeof(char)*4);
```

So if m is decrementing it wants to take user input from the console in the form of a string, but really a char, and save each char in the next index in the temp[]?  len is the number of chars in that array that have actually been initialized? Does this mean len == m?  And then memset is just setting 4 indices of each 3rd dimension array to null?

What I am expecting here is the user to enter a sequence of n chars to be saved in temp and then depending on how many chars are in the sequence prepare a 3d array of stuff[n][n][4] all filled with zeroes. It's just the while statements seem sort of excessive for just taking in what is basically a string.

Any help would be great. I have never done anything with C++ before and I've figure it all out except this one last part. I'm sorry this is so long but I was trying to show what I've been thinking.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf can give you an overview of these functions.

Comment: Could the downvoters please leave a comment? This is one of the better questions i have read today...

Comment: Thanks Gyro, I actually did look things up and used the cplusplus site a ton today which is why I thought it was C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(scanf("%d",&m)!=EOF)
```

Read an integer as input into `m`, until no input remains.

```
while(m--)
```

Yes, exactly equivalent to `for(; m>=0; m--)`.

> So if m is decrementing it wants to take user input from the console in the form of a string, but really a char, and save each char in the
>   next index in the temp[]? len is the number of chars in that array
>   that have actually been initialized? Does this mean len == m? And then
>   memset is just setting 4 indices of each 3rd dimension array to null?

The code reads some text into `temp`, which is an array of `char`.  `strlen(temp)` determines how long the text in `temp` is (it counts forward until it sees a zero `char`, which is how a text string is terminated in C).  So no, `len != m`.  And you're correct about the role of `memset`.

> What I am expecting here is the user to enter a sequence of n chars to
>   be saved in temp and then depending on how many chars are in the
>   sequence prepare a 3d array of stuff[n][n][4] all filled with zeroes.

Yes, this is exactly what happens.

Comment: So, if while(m--) decrements once for each char entered. It would be more efficient then to just do the nested loop memset part just once at the end since each time m decrements memset is writing over what it did before anyway?

Comment: `m--` decrements once for each _word_ read in by `scanf("%s",temp)`, not for each char.  And you're right, one `memset` at the end based on the largest value of `len` encountered during the loop would make more sense.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense then since temp should only be one word long. I think my confusion came from the extra features of this code when I was expecting something simpler.

Answer (score 2):

java and c syntax are not so far apart that you should have trouble reading this if you know java. While loops, for loops, code blocks that go with each, and variable pre/post incrementation/decrementation are pretty much identical.

`scanf()` is a complicated beast but you've got the gist of how you're using it… it reads from the standard input path and in your case, it reads an integer (%d is for an int; google "man scant" for full details), placing it into `m`. You have a loop to read this input, then perform a code block based on the new value of `m`.

The `while (m--)` block is just like the for loop you suggested, and it would also work in this same manner in java.

`scanf("%s")` reads a character string, not a just a character… the string will be NULL terminated but there's no guarantee (without doing more) that the input won't exceed the size of the buffer (`temp`).

`strlen()` returns the length of the string (not including it's NULL termination).

`memset(buffer, value, length)` writes `value` into memory beginning at `buffer`, for a total of `length` bytes. Google "man memset" for docs.

Comment: Ok, let's say in Java temp = {'a', 'b', 'c'} was just hard coded in. Would it be equivalent to just remove both whiles and just have len=3?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) are commands used in C mostly, although they can be used in C++ as well.

As for the `while(m--)`

Is the same as `for (int i = m; i > 0; i--)`